python sftp make it upload faster?
I normally use FileZilla to upload my video files to my own server. But filezilla hardcodes a limit of 10 transfers at a time due to TCP headers limitations or something like that.
And I don't like that. So I wanted to try to write my own python script that uses sftp to upload my video files. Also this allows me to automate the file name sanitation which previously I was doing manually.
My network setup is very simple:
local win 10 PC, 12 cores --> wifi --> ethernet switch --> ubuntu server
Here is my code:
https://github.com/jzoudavy/bulkSFTP/blob/main/main.py
and here is my result when compared against FileZilla:



12 CPU cores





10 workers



Test 1
6 files


Total size
5.38 GB


Applications
time (min)


FileZilla
5


Windows terminal
8.77






Test 2
8 files


Total size
7.17 GB


Applications



FileZilla
5


Windows terminal
6.68






Test 3
24 files


Total size
16.3 GB


Applications
time


FileZilla
11


Windows terminal
12






Test 4 (20 workers)
24 files


Total size
16.3 GB


Applications
time


FileZilla
11


Windows terminal
11



I don't have good timing data for filezilla because it doesn't seem to log how long each job takes once it finishes it so I just eyeballed it with the windows clock.
Script timing was done via the time module and only includes the part where I spin out threads to do the sftp transfer, because there is a fair bit of code that is devoted to cleaning up file names and creating the directories, which if I were doing via FileZilla I would be doing it manually.
The result is interesting because it seems the bigger the transfer, the less of a difference between my script and filezilla.
I also tried to increase the worker threads to 20 even though I only have 12 cpus (test 3 vs test 4) but it didn't improve things much.
I ran the code via cmd prompt so I could use process explorer and see it really did spun out the number of threads I coded for. (cause that was cool).
My question: is there anyway to make this faster or have I hit the limit?

I don't think the number of CPUs is the bottleneck here. Transferring files is an I/O bound task, so the amount of compute doesn't matter that much. Theoretically, the higher the number of parallel transmissions (threads) the better, until you make fully use of the available network bandwidth. You could probably speed things up by connecting your computer with an Gigabit Ethernet cable to your network or optimizing your WiFi setup (WiFi 6, no other devices, no barriers, etc.).

Agreed, making it 1G ethernet would probably improve throughput, but it would require me to drill through a floor and a load bearing wall so will have to make do with wifi for now. :)

Your  code should be posted in the question, not linked on another site. See [ask]. If you don't think the code is relevant then this is not a programming question, and it should not be here at all.

@D.Zou Is the direct way the only possible? Maybe you could take a detour to connect your PC to the router. On the software side, FileZilla is actually open source, you could study its source code to find out which magic they use to speed up transfers.

Besides, your data shows that the more files you transmit, the smaller the difference between FileZilla and our script. If the number of files is small, you could consider splitting up the largest files and transfer their parts concurrently. Just cut them in half and treat them as different files.
